# storing y co-ordinates in a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript, coordinates

I am trying to tween a movie clip's y position on a mouse click. So far I have this code

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;

import fl.transitions.easing.*;


var posY:Number = infographic_mc.y
var redY:Number = -232
var orangeY:Number = -551
var yellowY:Number = -883
var greenY:Number = -1225
var blueY:Number = -1543
var purpleY:Number = -1873

var tween1:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, redY, 2, true);
var tween2:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, orangeY, 2, true);
var tween3:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, yellowY, 2, true);
var tween4:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, greenY, 2, true);
var tween5:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, blueY, 2, true);
var tween6:Tween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, posY, purpleY, 2, true);

tween1.stop();
tween2.stop();
tween3.stop();
tween4.stop();
tween5.stop();
tween6.stop();

red_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redButtonClick);  
orange_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, orangeButtonClick);  
yellow_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yellowButtonClick);  
green_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, greenButtonClick);  
blue_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, blueButtonClick);  
purple_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, purpleButtonClick);  


function redButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween1.start();

 }


function orangeButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween2.start();
}


function yellowButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween3.start();
}


function greenButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween4.start();
}


function blueButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween5.start();
}


function purpleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

tween6.start();
}
```

This works but it doesn't store the Y co-ordinate after a tween and each tween goes back to the beginning.

Is there a way of updating the variable that is storing the Y co-ordinate in the mouseClick function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all the tweens at the beginning, you could have a variable to store your current tween.

```
var currentTween:Tween;
```

Then in each event listener, you can create your current tween based on the infographic_mc current position. The code would look something like this:

```
function redButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
   if(currentTween) currentTween.stop(); //if there is a current tween animating, stop it

   currentTween = new Tween(infographic_mc, "y", Regular.easeOut, infographic_mc.y, redY, 2, true);

   currentTween.start();
}
```

Also, I would suggest having one handler function for all buttons instead of separate function and use a switch statement to figure what button was clicked. Also, if you're planning to use a lot of animations in your application, take a look at the GreenSock library for tweening as it has a better performance.